# libvlc and gtk (for GUI) don't work together?

Tags: gtk, libvlc

I'm trying to use libvlc and gtk+ together without succeed. I think there is a problem with the `libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow()` function that I use for a GUI. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>

libvlc_media_t *media_played;
libvlc_media_player_t *is_play;
void Play(gpointer frame, GtkButton * button);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  libvlc_instance_t * instance = libvlc_new(0,NULL);
  libvlc_media_player_t *player = libvlc_media_player_new(instance);
  is_play = player;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  char Files[256];
  int i =0;
  printf("enter file name plus path, replace scape by '=' character\n");
  scanf("%s", Files);
  for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
      if(Files[i] == '=') Files[i] = ' ';
  }
  libvlc_media_t *media = libvlc_media_new_path(instance, Files);
  media_played = media;
  libvlc_media_player_set_media(player, media);
  GtkWidget * window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  GtkWidget * table = gtk_table_new(1,2,FALSE);
  GtkWidget * table1 = gtk_table_new(1,1,TRUE);
  GtkWidget *frame = gtk_frame_new(NULL);
  gtk_frame_set_shadow_type(GTK_FRAME(frame),GTK_SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT);
  GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Play");
  g_signal_connect_swapped(GTK_BUTTON(button),"clicked",G_CALLBACK(Play),(gpointer)frame);  
  libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow(player, GDK_WINDOW_XID(frame->window));
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table1),button,0,1,0,1,GTK_FILL,GTK_FILL,0,0);
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table),table1,0,1,0,1,GTK_FILL,GTK_FILL,0,0);
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table),frame,1,2,0,1,GTK_FILL,GTK_FILL,0,0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),table);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}

void Play(gpointer frame, GtkButton * button)
{
   char * title = libvlc_media_get_meta(media_played, libvlc_meta_Title);
   printf("vlc will play: %s\n", title);
   int64_t Time = libvlc_media_get_duration(media_played);
   libvlc_media_player_play(is_play);
   Time = Time/1000;
   clock_t c = clock();
   clock_t t = c;
   while((c/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<( Time + t))
   {
        c = c + clock();
   }
   gtk_widget_destroy(((GTK_WIDGET(frame)->parent)->parent));
   gtk_main_quit();
}
```

When running, it gives me an error like this:

```
(vlc1:7774): Gdk-WARNING **: /build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.24.10/gdk/x11/gdkdrawable-x11.c:952 drawable is not a pixmap or window
```

Someone has a solution??

Comment: I want to embed vlc in my gtk GUI interface but, good arrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely because when you make the call `libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow` in your code, `frame` (or more correctly top level window) is not yet realized and `GdkWindow` associated with it i.e. `frame->window` has not been created. Move the call `libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow` after `gtk_widget_show_all(window);` in the code and check your application.
It may be a good idea to use [`gtk_widget_get_window`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-window) instead of dereferencing `GtkWidget` pointer to get associated `GdkWindow` i.e. `gtk_widget_get_window(frame)` instead of `frame->window`
Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried that, effectively, call libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow after gtk_widget_show() works but, even with gtk_widget_get_window(), libvlc takes all the space provided. It seems that it is not possible to draw on a GtkFrame widget because it runs perfectly with GtkdrawingArea the movie take exactly the space's GtkdrawingArea.

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe: Well I have not really used `libvlc` as such, but it looks like you are providing the complete window for rendering of the video. When you provide xid of the window, the video will be rendered on the window. Hmm what exactly are you looking for? Restrict the area of video rendering?

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe: That is right. Frame does not have a window of its own i.e. it does not have X11 window associated with it but instead uses that of the top level window. But in case of Drawing area there is a separate x11 window associated with it which is not the same as top level window. This is reason why use observe the behaviour

Comment: I have a question, you said that:   "it looks like you are providing the complete window for rendering of the video" but GtkWidget structure has a GdkWindow member call "window"which is a GdkDrawable object and I have understood that we could drawn on it, set many pixels on it etc... this is why I use frame->window but you have said that a gtkframe widget doesn't have a X11 window associated and that it use the X11 window of its toplevel window so I have understood that frame->window and window->window point to the same gdkwindow.

Comment: When I make a brief looking at the gtk+ site on the gtk+ manual reference there is nothing tell me that this widget or this widget don't have a X11 window. Could you give me a tutorial which gives me all of this details?? it is crucial for making good thing. Thanks a lot for your help, now I know exactly the problem since many days.

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe: Couple of clarifications (I might have mislead you due to bad wording) `GdkWindow` associated with `GtkWidget` is *not* X11 window. `GdkWindow` happens to *abstract* the window and for X11 windowing system `GdkWindow` *maps* to X11 window. It is not mandatory that for every `GdkWindow` there is a unique X11 window associated with it. With that clarification when you use `GDK_WINDOW_XID` you are trying to get id of the X11 window associated with `GdkWindow`. This way you are making your application non-portable on other windowing systems i.e. it is guaranteed to work ...

Comment: ... for X11 windowing system alone. To determine if or not the widget has its own *GdkWindow* you can use [gtk_widget_get_has_window](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-has-window) from version 2.18 onwards. Maybe you can work with that. Using a drawing area as you have experimented with might a good option. `GtkDrawingArea` has its own `GdkWindow`

Comment: thanks, I have understood. GdkWindow just matchs a real window on x11 windowing system, it is a wrapper, it just keeps some informations about the corresponding x11 resource. GDK_WINDOW_XID give us the ID of the real window in the X server. But with gtk+ is there another windowing system to use a real window for drawing etc ?

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe: You are right. `GdkWindow` is an abstraction of window. It may not match one-to-one with X11 window in newer version. There are others windowing systems like on Linux there is [wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/), for Windows there is win32, Quartz for Mac OS. You can see these back-ends in the Gtk source. These provide the windows for rendering. For actual drawing [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) is used as well. The source code structure will give a lot of info about all these